# Access back-end messages (not the one from the event)

Tags: gmail-addons

I once wrote a GMail widget that I had to convert to a Chrome add-on when Google removed support for the GMail widget, and I'm now trying to convert it to a Gmail Add-on.

My issue is that my add-on loops thru a series of messages under a label and tries to reply to them, but I get a error trying to access them:

> ERROR: Exception: Access denied: : Missing access token for per message scope authorization.

So my question is, how can I access those messages? The only access token I have is the one that triggered the add-on and that won't do.

Or asking from a different point of view, are there more events that can trigger the add-on besides opening a message?

Thanks in advance.

BTW, the Chrome extension that I'm trying to convert to a Gmail add-on can be seen here:

https://sites.google.com/site/replytomany/home

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reply-to-many/gpmpcjkhfjflmjpjjmdegpkgginijbin?hl=en

[EDIT] This is what my appsscript.json looks like:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Dublin",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", 
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
         ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Reply To Many",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/receipt_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#41f470",
    "secondaryColor": "#94f441",
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i see the code for your access token and your appsscript.json file?

Comment: @Ronnie, I quite don't understand what you mean by "code for your access token"... If you're referring to the event metadata.accessToken I'm not using it at all because my script does not need to interact with the opened message. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are trying to reply to the emails you're looping through, so it does seem to imply you're needing an access token.  I would try implementing one to see if that's it.  Or it could be in your scope.  I see you have the send scope, but you may also need the scope to manage labels or the compose scope.  In this regard, I would just try "https://mail.google.com/" which gives you full access to see if your scope is the problem.  If that works, then you can just choose the correct scope your lacking.

Comment: I tried several combinations  of scopes, including that mail.google.com but now I'm stuck with "You do not have permission to call getActiveUser" - thing that I ever had, I don't if I messed with the scopes too much... Any idea on this one?

Comment: Just to clarify a little more, the original error I have in my post was when accessing message properties using the GmailApp API. Now I'm using both  that one and the Gmail API, I can now read message properties with this last one but I'm stuck sending a reply email, thing that with the GmailApp  was fairly simple. So I'm stuck one way or another....

Comment: Did you try implementing the access token?  I meant for you to try that first as I believe that's your issue if you don't have it.    // Activate temporary Gmail access token.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

Comment: if you have  "mail.google.com/", then you don't have a scope problem, as that gives you full access.  The only other security issue is the access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try implementing the access token? I meant for you to try that first as I believe that's your issue if you don't have it.

```
// Activate temporary Gmail access token. Where 'e' is the function argument
var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken; 
GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
```

if you have "mail.google.com/", then you don't have a scope problem, as that gives you full access. The only other security issue is the access token.

Comment: I did, but that will work only for the current message - the one is open is the UI - and not to the ones I'm looping thru. As per the docs, "Sets the current message access token that enables the script to access the current GmailMessage properties".

Comment: I think it works now!!! It seems the token is not necessary at all and the mess I had with the scopes AFAICS happened because it's not enough to change the oauthScopes and reload Gmail but at least sometimes it's necessary to remove the entire access to the app and authorize everything again!!!

The good thing here is that it works with the GmailApp API only, so I don't have to mess with the other Gmail API - that means it works with practically the same code I have for the Chrome extension... If I knew all this about the scopes I could have done the porting in less then 1 day!!!

Comment: Yea each time you add a new scope, you have to authorize the app again.  Which scope worked?

Comment: It was not a question of authorize again, I had to remove all the previous authorizations and start again from scratch. I ended up with this scope (maybe I'll try to narrow that down):

    www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute
    www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
    mail.google.com/

Comment: yea it was the www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope you needed.  Congrats!

Comment: @amsmota how did you remove all previous authorizations for your addon?

Comment: @ack_inc, you should have authorizations for add-ons somewhere in your Google account settings, I don't know exactly where because I followed the link they sent me by email when I first authorized the add-on. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
I believe that's the one you need if you're calling the Session object, 'getActiveUser'

if this doesn't fix your issue, I don't believe I can help without seeing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I had that but then I must have removed when messing the scopes... I put it back again, that one is gone! Cheers.